# How to re-enable function keys in byobu?

Tags: byobu

I was using byobu on Ubuntu 11.10 Server and I needed to hit a function key in an app, so I hit <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring up the config menu and switched the keybinding set from "f-keys" to "screen-escape-keys".  That worked, but now I can't re-enable all the f-keys.

I found a program [`byobu-config`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/byobu-config) that brings up the menu again, and I can switch back to screen keys from there.  This fixes things for new screen processes, but the effect on the current screen session is weird: it disables the <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> (screen) keys and restores <kbd>F2-F8</kbd>, but <kbd>F9-F12</kbd> still don't do anything (they're just passed on to the foreground process).

What's up with this?  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Note: This **only** works if you're using Byobu with `tmux` as the back-end. See other answers for Byobu with `screen` as the back-end.

---

Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> To toggle F-keys on and off.

Example : Launch [htop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hardy/htop) (within a Byobu pane of course) then enter <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, then if you press <kbd>F3</kbd> you will search in [htop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hardy/htop) processes, *not* switch to the left Byobu window/pane.

[Related question with answer also for *screen*.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146585/how-do-i-make-the-f-keys-work-in-byobu-for-midnight-commander-mc-htop-etc)

Comment: Note to future self: ignore the accepted answer status - this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was struggling to figure out why I can't switch windows all of a sudden.

Comment: Does not work any more... (using ubuntu 12.04.1)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I guess this does not work on byobu-screen. Check @Dustin Kirkland's answer if does not work for you and you use byobu-screen.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04 with Tmux as well

Comment: Ahhhh. I don't know how mine got (partially?) disabled, but F3 and F4 were outputting `OR` or `OS` for some reason. This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 14):

You can also toggle between the `f-keys` bindings and the `screen-escape-keys` bindings using:

```
ctrl-a-!
```

Comment: Here this displays the message "can't break with only one pane" are you sure of this shortcut ?

Comment: That only works in byobu-screen, not in byobu-tmux (https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/386363).
In the latter the correct combination is SHIFT-F12.

Comment: This *does* work on Ubuntu 12.04.1 (NOTE: answer SHIFT-F12 does not work)

Comment: Note that this will also reset your meta/escape key, probably because it just sources `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.screen.disable` which has the line `escape ^Aa`. If you for example used 't' as your escape key you can set it again by hitting ctrl-a and then `:escape ^Tt`.

Answer (score 4):

We can attempt to debug your particular problem, however it would be much easier to just clean out your Byobu configuration and start clean:

```
rm -rf ~/.byobu
```

On 11.04, you'll also need to remove the folder this symlink points to:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/byobu
```

And then start `byobu`.

Answer (score 2):

In case any of the key combinations from the other answers did not work, just try this equivalent command inside Byobu:

```
byobu-keybindings
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `~/.byobu/keybindings` look like this:

```sh
# source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/common
. /usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.screen.disable
```

and select screen as byobu's back-end via `byobu-select-backend`. That works in Debian, at least.