# How do I make the F-keys work in byobu, for midnight commander (mc), htop, etc?

Tags: command-line, screen, byobu, tmux

I use byobu with the tmux backend on my 12.04 server. I'd like to use the midnight commander shortcut keys with it, but the F keys don't work.

I've seen some posts on the issues here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/386363
- https://answers.launchpad.net/byobu/+question/127610

but they are out of date and don't seem to work for newer versions of byobu. How can I either work around this or use MC in a way that works better?

Comment: Same goes for htop and others.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can easily toggle on/off the use of the F-keys inside of Byobu (tmux) by pressing either:

- <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> (in tmux)
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd> (in screen)

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.*

Comment: How do you make it off by default, and turn it on as needed? @Dustin-Kirkland

Comment: Got it, add `source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable` to your .byobu/keybindings.tmux at the end

Comment: @Dustin The second one works perfectly for me. However, after toggling F-keys on and off, I have to confirm the escape sequence again using F9 before I can toggle F-keys on again.

Comment: not working :P any of this key bindings

Comment: Dustin, while that works fine for most keys, Shift-Fx seems to be completely ignored by mc when running in Byobu (with Tmux here). I can understand that for shift-F12 (for obvious reasons) – but what do I miss for e.g. Shift-F3 or Shift-F4 (which I frequently need)?

Comment: @Dustin: it would be nice to add those short cuts also in the shift-F1 documentation! I was looking for this for a while!  Thanks!

Comment: You could also use `byobu-keybindings` command, equivalent to those key combinations.

Comment: @dustin-kirkland can you put in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu how to make it work in Putty? CTRL+F2 doesnt work in putty. Also Launchpad does not know where byobu tracks support requests. https://answers.launchpad.net/byobu BUG REPORT https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1882373

Comment: If you are on a Chromebook and you think you only have F1 through F10, you should know that you can use the number row with the super key (search) to enter F-keys. Now you can enter F-keys F11 and F12.

Answer (score 13):

On **midnight commander** to trigger for example the <kbd>F2</kbd> key:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (simultaneously)
- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> (one after the other).

Which is more convenient than switching using:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (in tmux, default on byobu)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd> (in screen)

Comment: This is useful mostly when you use MC inside byobu on Mac OS X, since some F-keys are already used by the system. I find myself using `ESC`, `9` quite often.

Comment: Any way to extend that to Shift-Fx? Even with Byobu keybindings disabled, Shift-Fx seem to be "blind" (don't work). Tried Esc--Shift-4, no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Hah, a man after my own heart :)

Short answer: add [my ppa](https://launchpad.net/~izx/+archive/private) (`ppa:izx/private`) and `update` byobu (or manually install the deb). Byobu will default to `screen` as the backend with <kbd>F</kbd>-key behavior restored to old 4.x style.

Long answer: Use `byobu-select-backend` to switch to `screen` if you haven't already, and add line `$BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.screen.disable` after the line `$BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.screen` in `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/common`.

Entire patch:

```
+++ byobu-5.17/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/common
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.screen
+source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.screen.disable
+
--- byobu-5.17.orig/etc/byobu/backend
+++ byobu-5.17/etc/byobu/backend
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 # BYOBU_BACKEND can currently be "screen" or "tmux"
 # Override this on a per-user basis by editing "$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/backend"
 # or by launching either "byobu-screen" or "byobu-tmux" instead of "byobu".
-#BYOBU_BACKEND="tmux"
+BYOBU_BACKEND="screen"
```

Comment: But what if we wanted to keep it with tmux?

Comment: @jrg: I'm not that familiar with tmux, sorry -- I tried the new byobu but after [this now-fixed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byobu/+bug/952724), switched back to the screen-backend because I'm used to it and happy with it, whatever its limitations.